# AsyncTask: doInBackground not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with the `AsyncTask`. Sometimes the `doInBackground()` method is not called after `onPreExecute()`.

I know this question was asked several times but the given answers don't work for me.

Here is a part of my code:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");
    };

};

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
else
    asyncTask.execute();
```

As you can see, I check if the Android version is >= HoneyComb and execute the task in the Pool Executor if it's true.
Even with that "trick" sometimes `doInBackground()` is not called.

Does somebody have the same issue or knows how what's the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes I have this problem if there's already an AsyncTask running - is that possible?

Comment: post full code. it could be for a number of things

Comment: Cornholio: Yes it's true. Other AsyncTasks are running. (I precise they are other instances of AsyncTasks, not the same executed several times)

Comment: Have you tried to override onCancelled() to see if you get any error? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled(Result)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finaly I found a solution to the problem.

Instead of execute the asyncTask with the *AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR*, I instanciate my own ThreadPoolExecutor with a large corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize:

```
int corePoolSize = 60;
int maximumPoolSize = 80;
int keepAliveTime = 10;

BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maximumPoolSize);
Executor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
```

And ...

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
```

I don't know if this is a good bugfix but with this, doInBackground() is always called. 
As you said, I supose that the problem was that *AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR* could not manage as much asyncTasks as I gave to it.

Thank you guys

Comment: Note that this solution is not valid for 2.3.X devices, where you'll have to resort to `asyncTask.execute();`

Comment: Anyone got solution for 2.3.X? It works perfectly fine for other versions above that.

Comment: @Valentin, Great solution !

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me one time because some of my tasks were blocked in the `doInBackground()` (which is obviously impossible with the code sample you pasted).

The default pool size on Android for the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR was 5 the last time I have checked. So if you execute more than 5 tasks at the same time the next ones will wait until a task is finished.

It's the only case I known to prevent a `doInBackground()` call.

Comment: "The default pool size on Android for the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR was 5 the last time I have checked. So if you execute more than 5 tasks at the same time the next ones will wait until a task is finished."

This is interresting. If there is already 5 tasks in the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR and that I add a sixth into it, what will be the behaviour?

1) The sixth task will never execute doInBackground()
or
2) The sixth task will wait another task to be finished before to be executed

Comment: when one task finishes, the 6th one will start. I'd expect `onPreExecute` to be called only now but never really checked.

Comment: @Valentin Yes the sixth is queued. Note that if you really need to run more than 5 tasks at the same time, you can intantiate your own executor with a bigger `CORE_SIZE`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

You can only run async tasks once. I'm guessing that you are trying to run them several times.

Create another instance and try again.

If it doesn't works, check the logcat and post it here if it's not enough for you to fix it.

Comment: This instance of AsyncTask is only executed once :/
However, other instances of AsyncTask are running. Is there a maximum of AsyncTask that I can give to the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR ?

Comment: check logcat for any errors then. There are no limits to the number of tasks you submit