# Why AsyncTask work correctly only 2 times?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I open new `Activity` I run new `AsyncTask` to update `TextView` in real time. When `Activity` is finish `AsyncTask` is canceled. When I open and close this `Activity` two times, everything runs correct. But on third time and every other - `doInBackground` method is never started, despite that Task status is "RUNNING". Code looks like this.

Open Activity:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            final String selectedFromList = (list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NetworkText", txts.getText());
            intent.putExtra("ChooseCompTitle", new String(selectedFromList));
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
        }
    });
```

"onCreate" start execute AsyncTask:

```
ConnectionDataPack supportDesktopData;
UpdateTextView taskUpdateText;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    . . . .

    final TextView txts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
    final TextView textContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("NetworkText") != null){
        txts.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("NetworkText"));
    }

    if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ChooseCompTitle") != null){
        supportDesktopData = findFitCompPack(getIntent().getExtras().getString("NetworkText"), MainActivity.connectComputer);
    }
    else finish();

    taskUpdateText = new UpdateTextView(supportDesktopData, textContent, scroll);
    taskUpdateText.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    if(taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
        Log.i("LogsX", "AsyncTask has not started yet.");
    }
    if(taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        Log.i("LogsX", "AsyncTask is currently doing work.");
    }
    if(taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        Log.i("LogsX", "AsyncTask is done");
    }
   . . . .

}
```

I also override finish method:

```
 public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    if(!taskUpdateText.isCancelled()) {
        Log.i("LogX", "End AsyncTask!");
        taskUpdateText.cancel(true);
    }
    else Log.i("LogX", "Asynctask is already cancell!");
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
}
```

because i must close this AsyncTask when Activity is finish.

AsyncTask look like this:

```
class UpdateTextView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    int lengthTextBuffor = 0;

    ConnectionDataPack compDataPack;
    TextView textUpdate;
    ScrollView scrool;

    public UpdateTextView(ConnectionDataPack compDataPack, TextView textUpdate, ScrollView scrool)
    {
        this.compDataPack = compDataPack;
        this.textUpdate = textUpdate;
        this.scrool = scrool;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
          textUpdate.setText(compDataPack.dataBackupCharacter.toString());
            scrool.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.i("LogX", "doInBackground Starts!");
        boolean startLoop = true;
        while(true)
        {
               synchronized (compDataPack.lock){
                if(!startLoop && lengthTextBuffor == compDataPack.dataBackupCharacter.length()) {
                    try {
                        compDataPack.lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }   
                startLoop = false;
                publishProgress();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all answers, but it seems I found solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851515/7392319). It works for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code..

```
if (taskUpdateText != null && taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
            taskUpdateText.execute();
        } else if (taskUpdateText == null || taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            taskUpdateText = new UpdateTextView();
            taskUpdateText.execute();
        }
```

and in onDestroy() put the below code

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (taskUpdateText != null && taskUpdateText.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            taskUpdateText.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with these might be your asyntask not gets garbage collected or it is still running in background.

Try to use below code

```
@override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(taskUpdateText!=null) {
            taskUpdateText.cancel(true);
            taskUpdateText = null;
        }

}
```